# foreach and echo data from flight XML

Tags: php, xml

I have flight XML and I must parse and sort it.

The XML has Options, Segments and Return Segments. Segments and Return Segments depend Options.

XML structure:

```html
<Options>
<ID>0</ID>
<No>1100</No>
<Tprice>414.53</Tprice>
<Nprice>127</Nprice>
<Adults>1</Adults>
<Childs>0</Childs>
<Baby>0</Baby>
<AdultTprice>414.53</AdultTprice>
<ChildTprice>0</ChildTprice>
<BabyTprice>0</BabyTprice>
<AdultNprice>127</AdultNprice>
<ChildNprice>0</ChildNprice>
<BabyNprice>0</BabyNprice>
<ServiceFee>45.0000</ServiceFee>
<FlightTime>20170226</FlightTime>
<Support>Galileo</Support>
</Options>
```

```html
<Segments>
<ID>0</ID>
<OptionsID>0</OptionsID>
<FlightID>0</FlightID>
<Transit>false</Transit>
<FlightNo>8076</FlightNo>
<FlightCode/>
<AirLine>Azerbaijan Airlines</AirLine>
<AirLineKod>J2</AirLineKod>
<OriginCode>IST</OriginCode>
<OriginCodeID>0</OriginCodeID>
<OriginCountry>Türkiye</OriginCountry>
<OriginCity>İstanbul</OriginCity>
<OriginAirport>Atatürk</OriginAirport>
<ToCode>GYD</ToCode>
<ToCodeID>0</ToCodeID>
<ToCountry>Azerbaijan</ToCountry>
<ToCity>Baku</ToCity>
<ToAirport>Heydar Aliyev Intl Arpt</ToAirport>
<FlightDuration>165</FlightDuration>
<TotalFlightDuration>165</TotalFlightDuration>
<OriginFlightTime>2017-03-14T13:20:00+03:00</OriginFlightTime>
<ToFlightTime>2017-03-14T17:05:00+03:00</ToFlightTime>
<Time>Ogle</Time>
<Class>P</Class>
<ClassTip>Ekonomi</ClassTip>
</Segments>


<ReturnSegments>
<ID>0</ID>
<OptionsID>0</OptionsID>
<FlightID>3</FlightID>
<Transit>false</Transit>
<FlightNo>8075</FlightNo>
<FlightCode/>
<AirLine>Azerbaijan Airlines</AirLine>
<AirLineKod>J2</AirLineKod>
<OriginCode>GYD</OriginCode>
<OriginCodeID>0</OriginCodeID>
<OriginCountry>Azerbaijan</OriginCountry>
<OriginCity>Baku</OriginCity>
<OriginAirport>Heydar Aliyev Intl Arpt</OriginAirport>
<ToCode>IST</ToCode>
<ToCodeID>0</ToCodeID>
<ToCountry>Türkiye</ToCountry>
<ToCity>İstanbul</ToCity>
<ToAirport>Atatürk</ToAirport>
<FlightDuration>185</FlightDuration>
<TotalFlightDuration>185</TotalFlightDuration>
<OriginFlightTime>2017-03-28T08:45:00+03:00</OriginFlightTime>
<ToFlightTime>2017-03-28T10:50:00+03:00</ToFlightTime>
<Time>Sabah</Time>
<Class>P</Class>
<ClassTip>Ekonomi</ClassTip>
</ReturnSegments>
```

This is the XML structure and I want to  parse it, then collect all data together and echo it all together. Options, Segments and Return Segments must be together for `foreach`, because when I echo it I can echo only together.

Because in Options id there is price, segments and returnsegments have details. All flight ticketsale websites you can see the structure but I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Take a look at either `DOMDocument` & `DOMXPath` or `simpleXML` - there are plenty of examples of both here on stack or elsewhere on the interwebs

Comment: This is not that i search

Comment: I need parse it and echo this together